# Java Hibernate Restcrition Criteria OR with DetachedCritera

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TableA.class)
        .add(Subqueries.propertyNotIn("id_a", DetachedCriteria.forClass(TableB.class)
        .createAlias("id_a_from_tableB", "b")
        setProjection(Property.forName("b.id_a"))));
```

I use this to get **id_a** from **TableA** if **id_a** is not in **TableB**. I need also get **id_a** if is in **TableB** but field "message" is not null.

Comment: And what is already working and what  isn't?

Comment: This is what I wrote works.(get id_a from TableA if id_a is not in TableB). I don't know how to add another criteria to check if in TableB where id_a_from_tableB is equal id_a from TableA  field "message" is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this post can [help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208743/how-to-perform-union-clause-query-with-hibernate-criteria-api).

> with criteria I think hibernate does not support `UNION ALL` but you
>   can use two criteria queries to get the expected result:
>
> ```
> Criteria cr1 = session.createCriteria(Suppliers.class);
>  cr1.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
>     .add( Projections.property("supplier_id"), "supplier_id" )
>  );
> List results1 = cr1.list();
>
> Criteria cr2 = session.createCriteria(Orders.class);
>  cr2.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
>     .add( Projections.property("supplier_id"), "supplier_id" )
>  );
> List results2 = cr2.list();
>
> results1.add(results2); 
>
> List unionAllList =  results1; //this is the expected result.
> ```

For example, you could add new criteria when you get from TableB if message is not null, and later just join two Java collections:

```
Criteria criteria1 = session.createCriteria(TableB.class)
.add( Restrictions.isNotNull("message")
```

**P.S.** Or I recommend using Criteria API from [JPA2.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) (Chapter 6) instead of hibernate Criteria, because it's look like simple SQL and this solution is much more universally.

Comment: I add sample in my post