# How to get data on the union of two criteria query using Criteria Api

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have a situation where I am fetching data in two queries based on different conditions and union them.

Now,I need to fetch data from the result of union of the given two queries based on some conditions. 
**Ist query:**

```
Criteria criteria = irisSessionFactory.getSession().createCriteria(Task.class,"tasks").add(
                    Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNull("claimedby"),Restrictions.eq("projects.projectname", projectName)));
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", "Check"));
                    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("disableCommit")).addOrder(Order.desc("taskid"));


            List<Task> tasks = criteria.list();
```

**2nd Query**

```
    Criteria criteria2 = irisSessionFactory.getSession().createCriteria(Task.class,"tasks").add(
            Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNull("claimedby"),Restrictions.eq("projects.projectname", projectName)));
            criteria2.add(Restrictions.ne("status", "Check"));
            criteria2.addOrder(Order.asc("taskid"));
            criteria2.addOrder(Order.asc("status"));

            List<Task> tasks2 = criteria2.list();
```

**Combining the result**

```
tasks.addAll(tasks2);
```

I want to create criteria on the UNION of these two criteria.
How I can proceed???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to perform union clause query with hibernate criteria api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208743/how-to-perform-union-clause-query-with-hibernate-criteria-api)

Comment: The way you have it is actually the correct way to do it as Criteria API does not have support for `UNION ALL`